# Counting of clients

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table and a list of client with respective id which transact to an item and I want them to count how many of that were my new client within the year and how many transaction per customer.

```html
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>UniqueID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>ReceiptNo</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100011</td>
    <td>04/15/2015</td>
    <td>CHINA</td>
    <td>495651633164117</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100012</td>
    <td>5/16/2014</td>
    <td>SINGAPORE</td>
    <td>902549556061179</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100013
    </td>
    <td>8/2/2019</td>
    <td>THAILAND
    </td>
    <td>250749065260758
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100013
    </td>
    <td>10/2/2015</td>
    <td>THAILAND
    </td>
    <td>554626060959714
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100015

    </td>
    <td>8/28/2016</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA

    </td>
    <td>171768803140265

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100016

    </td>
    <td>3/17/2021
</td>
    <td>TAIWAN

    </td>
    <td>820516048850062

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100017

    </td>
    <td>4/2/2016</td>
    <td>SINGAPORE

    </td>
    <td>218012057641382

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100017

    </td>
    <td>7/14/2021
</td>
    <td>SINGAPORE

    </td>
    <td>999105086662729

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100019

    </td>
    <td>6/25/2020
</td>
    <td>TAIWAN

    </td>
    <td>974479049682501

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CDR100020

    </td>
    <td>4/21/2020
</td>
    <td>CHINA

    </td>
    <td>668185025024787
    </td>

    </tr><tr>
    <td>CDR100021

    </td>
    <td>7/5/2020
</td>
    <td>MALAYSIA

    </td>
    <td>134049410374093

    </td>
    </tr><tr>
   

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Sample output: (don't count if id already exist)

```
Year Client
2014 1
2015 2
2016 2
2019 0 
2020 3
2021 1
```

Select count(uniqueid)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this;

`SELECT  extractedYear, COUNT(*) AS CLIENT  FROM (SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN(t.date)) AS extractedYear, t.`UniqueID  `FROM transactions t  GROUP BY t.UniqueID) a  GROUP BY extractedYear ;`

Answer (score 0):

that is no vaild mysql date, so please save dates always in mysql format yyyy-mm-dd.

Another problem, is that mysql has no possiblity to make easy time table, so you need tojoin the years as separate table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tansac (
>   `UniqueID` VARCHAR(9),
>   `Date` DATETIME,
>   `Country` VARCHAR(9),
>   `ReceiptNo` BIGINT
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tansac
>   (`UniqueID`, `Date`, `Country`, `ReceiptNo`)
> VALUES
>   ('CDR100011', STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2015','%m/%d/%Y'), 'CHINA', '495651633164117'),
>   ('CDR100012', STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2014','%m/%d/%Y'), 'SINGAPORE', '902549556061179'),
>   ('CDR100013', STR_TO_DATE('8/2/2019','%m/%d/%Y'), 'THAILAND', '250749065260758'),
>   ('CDR100013', STR_TO_DATE('10/2/2015','%m/%d/%Y'), 'THAILAND', '554626060959714'),
>   ('CDR100015', STR_TO_DATE('8/28/2016','%m/%d/%Y'), 'AUSTRALIA', '171768803140265'),
>   ('CDR100016', STR_TO_DATE('3/17/2021','%m/%d/%Y'), 'TAIWAN', '820516048850062');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t2.year_a as 'Year',IFNULL(trancations,0) as 'trancations'
> FROM
> (SELECT 2014 year_a
>             UNION SELECT 2015 
>             UNION SELECT 2016 
>             UNION SELECT 2017 
>             UNION SELECT 2018 
>             UNION SELECT 2019
>             UNION SELECT 2020
>             UNION SELECT 2021) t2
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEAR(`date`) as 'year', IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) as 'trancations'
> FROM tansac t1
> GROUP BY 1) t1   ON t1.`year` = t2.year_a
> ORDER BY 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Year | trancations
> ---: | ----------:
> 2014 |           1
> 2015 |           2
> 2016 |           1
> 2017 |           0
> 2018 |           0
> 2019 |           1
> 2020 |           0
> 2021 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e495cad9cd909548ed3797484ff1845)*

Comment: what if the data keeps increasing and there is an introduction of years like 2022, 2023,... and so on?

Comment: the best would be to have a separate table with the years, and there you can make one till 2525 for example, but for demonstration purposes i made a temporary table t2 and as i saud mysql has no time series, but we use time tables for that already made